# Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists

Tags: php, magento

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/core/resource" already exists
```

Trace:

```
#0 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/core...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource))
#2 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(141): Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
#3 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(234): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->__construct('core_setup')
#4 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/sourceciti/public_html/demo/nrrexports/demo/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

hello guys am getting this error,and all my design has gone,please help me how to solve this,please guys

Comment: Try flushing cache. empty var/cache folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try clearing cache of Magento.

If issue still exists, then check whether you have created or installed any module or extension which has any observer class.

If yes, then check its declaration and match that config.xml has correct way of declaration of observer.

After that clear Magento cache again.